# Unable to delete google cloud project due of dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to close my google cloud subscription by deleting all the available projects. I couldn't able to delete one of the projects either by ui or with the following command.

`gcloud projects delete projectid-123`

`ERROR: (gcloud.projects.delete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed.

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:

  - description: 'A lien to prevent deletion was placed on the project by [You cannot
    delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent. Please follow
    the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent: https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/e05152693a3
    Remove the lien to allow deletion.'
    subject: liens/45620bc6246c-l5cef9dc1
    type: LIEN
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:

  - description: Troubleshooting project deletion
    url: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/troubleshooting-project-deletion
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  reason: PROJECT_DELETE_LIEN`

I no longer have access to that agent now so couldn't able to delete it. How to delete my project now? Is there any way to unlink the service from my project?

Also I'm not sure why i couldn't access the agent now. It was created before dialogflow merged to google.

Comment: Are you the project Owner and Billing Administrator? If yes, open a Google Cloud Billing support explaining that you cannot shut down the project. They can tell you what to do next. The key item to explain is your last statement.

Comment: Yes I'm the project owner and billing administrator.
I already tried gcloud support, its either giving automatic reply or keeps on redirecting to new page. I even tried creating support case but free-tier user is not eligible to file tech-related support cases. Thats why posted in community space.

Comment: Google Cloud `Billing Support` is different than Google Cloud Support.